# Explicit modifier for constructors taking reference argument

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, explicit

I read that it's a good practice to define single argument constructors `explicit` in order to avoid implicit conversions. I understand the pitfall of having int value promoted to class object. I wonder if it also applies to the constructors accepting reference types. How one can provoke implicit conversion in this case:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar& bar) { }
};
```

Does the situation changes if the constructor accepts pointers, is conversion from `NULL` and `nullptr` possible ?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar* bar) { }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both. A function with signature

```
void acceptFoo(const Foo& foo)
```

will make the compiler to create a `Foo` if you pass a `Bar` there.

Same for `0` and `nullptr`.